# How to crash an Azure App Service Container

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

I am testing few scenario with my deployments while creating an Azure App Service with container.

I would like to crash my Azure Web App container. This container is setup from a docker image stored in Azure Container Registry. I am testing if the deployment all works fine. One of the scenario is to inject a crash in to my Azure Web App container to test auto container creation process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH enabled for your docker image you can go to the kudu site -> SSH. 
The kill the main process (using kill -9 PID) which will eventually kill the container as well.